# How do I get a cubed symbol in a text box?

Tags: uilabel

May seem like a silly question, but I simply want to have 'm'[cubed symbol] rather than 'cubic metres' in a text label in XCode.
How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need `³`, you can use the appropriate unicode character (Unicode: U+00B3, UTF-8: C2 B3). On the Mac you can use the "Character Viewer" (e.g. on "Edit" menu - "Special characters"), enter "3" in the search box, and then grab the appropriate "Related character". See the Apple help document [entering unicode characters](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1518) for more information.

If you need a more general use of subscripts (or you need more fine grained control over how the superscript is rendered), you can use attributed strings. Thus, the following will render something like "1,000 m<sup>3</sup>":

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.label.font.familyName size:self.label.font.pointSize * 0.75];
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"1,000 m3"];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{(id)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName : @(1),
                             (id)NSFontAttributeName         : font};
[string addAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(7, 1)];
```

Comment: Or just use the Unicode character for the superscript 3 - `³`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply insert the symbol in the string literal using *Edit > Special Characters...* (type "cubed" in the search box):

```
textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your table is %u㎤", tableVolume);
```

These are the unit-cubed symbols I found:

㎣ ㎤ ㎥ ㎦

If want a generic superscript '3' then that will be harder to arrange...

Comment: There is a superscript 3 (³). It's the character U+00B3. This allows for `m³` for example.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks; I couldn't find it.